# remember selected imageViews next time the user opens the app

Tags: android

So I'm making an app that presents the users with a grid of boxes and when they click on a box it presents them with a question. If they get the question right a tick appears where that particular box used to be, if they get it wrong the grid of boxes stays the same. The only trouble I am having is saving how far the user has got once the enter a new activity or close the app.

I have tried to search it up and could only find `onPause()`, which doesn't work because the information about what box the user has tapped is all in a single method and the value cannot be reached outside the method. The other option I saw was `sharedPreference` which I can't seem to understand how it relates to my problem.

Sorry for the super long message and many thanks for any reply!

Comment: the data you are populating is from database? if yes then user check mark the box add boolean against that record in database. if you comeback to activity the data with updated record will be populted from database. and marks those item selected by default with respect to the database. Hope that helps you

Comment: Why not make a List<Boxes> that stores all the boxes clicked?

Comment: I'm not populating this from a database. But many thanks for your reply!

Comment: How would I go about making a List of Boxes? I tried :  List<Boxes> boxesClicked = new List<Boxes>();

Comment: Your data is static or it's come from webservice?

Comment: My data is static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest either opening the question/answer in a fragment instead of a new activity. Alternatively, as you mentioned, I would suggest saving the checkboxes status in SharedPreferences, you can then read from the SharedPreferences once you go back to your checkboxes activity.
You can save to SharedPreferences, for each checkbox through something like (where box_1 is a checkbox):

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("appname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pref.edit().putBoolean("box_1", box_1.isChecked()).commit();
```

Repeat this for all the checkboxes. When you return to the checkboxes activity, just set them back according to the values stored earlier, like this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("appname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    box_1.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("box_1", false));
```

Comment: i am not preferring this answer.This is temporary solutions.We are not using sharedpreference for this.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I have an if statement that's determines whether the user is correct, so would you suggest setting them all to false, and if the user is correct then changing that box to true. then when retrieving the information make a loop and an if statement and say if true then put a tick? Also I last small question, does it matter where in my activity I put these lines of code? I.e do they have to go in the method where the value of the tapped box is? Many thanks! This is a massive help!

Comment: best to implement the code I posted whenever you change the status of a box to save the new status.
You should then load the sharedPrefs in your onCreate for the boxes activity and set all boxes one by one or looping over them if you have a lot. No need for "if" statements... just store the boolean values which you get from checkbox.isChecked() and restored them with checkbox.setChecked()...
hope it helps, good luck with your project :)

Comment: I understand your point but assume greed have 14 data then create 14 sharedpreferences so those are not valid idea.

Comment: you wouldn't create 14 sharedPrefs, you would only create one and store 14 values in it, each one under its own tag. the other solution it to use SQLite, which is really an overkill here and would slow performance for no real gain or advantage.
You should only really start using SQL and databases in general when you have a vast amount of data or data that expands and grows. I doubt that the number of checkboxes would programmatically increase here...

Comment: Hi fuzzKitty! I have solved the problem using your code there are 3 errors still. (all probably related to each other). The first is it 'cannot resolve method getSharedPreference'       It also cannot resolve method 'isChecked()'. I should of perhaps said the boxes are imageviews. Finally in the onCreate method, for 2nd bit of code (receiving the data) it cannot resolve method setChecked(). Any help much appreciated! Many thanks

Comment: hi, sorry, I assumed you were using checkboxes. If you are using imageviews you will then have to create your own setter that gets a boolean and your own getter which returns the status, also as a boolean. 
You need a context to use `getSharedPreferences` try to use a `getContext()` for this, like this... 

`SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("appname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: Hi again, this so useful, just to confirm, is this what you meant when you said the setters and getters: boolean status;

    public void setChecked(boolean torf){

            status = torf;

    }

    public boolean getSharedPrefernce(){

        return status;

    }

Comment: not exactly... I meant, setters and getters for your Question or Answer class, that take a boolean and return a boolean which you can use to save and restore the status of your boxes in the sharedPrefs

Comment: Brilliant! This helps massively! So I've set up the setters and getters in my Q and A class, I was just wondering how I would implement them in the SharedPreferences code?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to go with SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 2):

So my suggestions to you is saved those data into database and handling of check-box click on updating database through it's unique id of row so when you are closing application and again open your application at that time you have data as well as check-box click so at that time you are getting data from database and set those data  into model class and use `List<MobelClass>` those list are bing into recycler Grid Adapter.

This is best solution hope it's help to you.